# problems using setMeasuredDimension()

Tags: android, view, radio-button, inflate

I need my own RadioButton with a complex custom design (which is not
possible using nine-patch only).

So I tought about extending RadioButton and using all features from
RadioGroup.

For the complex custom design I inflate a LinearLayout (at first I
used RelativeLayout but it seems to throw a NullPointerException, so I
tried LinearLayout which works instead).

Well, I've got some issues measuring, layouting and drawing the
LinearLayout.

Let's assume there is this complex custom design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1"... >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tab_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"... />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tab_text" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"... />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is "new" view:

```
public class RadioView extends RadioButton {

    private LinearLayout container;
    private TextView count, text;

    public RadioView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       init(context);
    }

    public RadioView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       init(context);
    }

    public RadioView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       init(context);
    }

    private void init(final Context context) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       container = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ve_radio, null);
       count = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.tab_count);
       text = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
       container.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

       // here comes the problem
       setMeasuredDimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
       container.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       container.draw(canvas);
    }

}
```

Actually I don't know how to calculate the measured dimension. To be
honest I want the RadioGroup to calculate enough space for me and I
want to delegate this space to the inflated LinearLayout.

Thank you for helping me out on this.

Best Regards,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was quite simple :)

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    container.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(container.getMeasuredWidth(), container.getMeasuredHeight());
}
```

Right now I want to talk about the RelatriveLayout NullPointerException.

I changed the LinearLayout into RelativeLayout and this is what I get:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:472)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
at nu.style.RadioView.onMeasure(RadioView.java:84)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1196)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:555)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1163)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:312)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2072)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1044)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for any help.

Best regards,
Marco